# How to recover data after memory module errors

Tags: ubuntu, memory, corruption

My linux PC has suffered the occasional application crash, desktop crash, and kernal panic over the last few months. I also started noticing error dialogs on login, and some parts of the desktop do not look the same. Over the last week, this crash rate has increased to more than 3 per day, so I investigated with logs and diagnostics.

The MemTest86 program indicated a memory module fault. I removed the faulty module and my system is now stable.

My problem is there are many inital errors and small failures (eg: cups printing, an icon missing from the toolbar, the purple bacground disappeared from the Ununtu boot screen, etc), that suggest bit errors during configuration writes or `apt-get upgrade` binary updates.

Is there a `apt-get checksum all-packages` type command that can check my binaries with a global repository (and perhaps re-install corrupted files)?

Debian installs have the `debsums` utility (as mention here: [Check and fix all files from Debian packages.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/check-and-fix-all-files-from-debian-packages)). Is there a similar utility in the Ubuntu world (using "apt")?

I would like to avoid a complete re-install of OS and all applications.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (14.04) 64 bit

Comment: That question (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/check-and-fix-all-files-from-debian-packages) is very similar, but I need a solution for Ubuntu, probably with the apt package manager. Is there a `debsums` for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, `apt-get install debsums` if it's not already installed.

Comment: Are the checksums downloaded with the binary or is the checksum calculated on the image in memory or on disk? My scan returned clean, but then it would if the checksums were computed from the binary image after the bit errors had already corrupted it. The checksum would only be used then to detect changes to files after the write to disk in this case. Do you know of a central checksum library that `debsums` can verify against?

Comment: The checksums are contained in the packages, so if `debsums` says everything's OK that means your binaries match those originally shipped (unless the checksums were miraculously corrupted to match the corrupted binaries, which is unlikely to say the least). See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/debsums.1.html) for details (the examples section is quite handy).

Comment: Thank you Stephen. You have saved me a lot of time. Should I delete this question, or leave it for Ubuntu people who may have the same issue?

Comment: Leave it here, I've flagged it to be closed as a duplicate but it might well help other Ubuntu users in the future.